# iOS call void in parentViewController from MPMoviePlayerViewController when dismissed

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, dismiss, parentviewcontroller

How can I call a custom -(void)  in the parentViewController of a MPMoviePlayerViewCotroller when is is dismissed?

Comment: Give more details on what you tried and what you are trying to achieve. Include some code too if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call it in the viewDidAppear of the parentViewController.

Set a flag before showing the MPMoviePlayerViewController and check it in viewDidAppear. Then call your own method accordingly.

Hope this helps.